# Div positioning mystery

Tags: html, css

Here is an simplified example of my real problem.

```
<div id="con">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
    <div id="c">
        <div id="d"></div>
        <div id="e">blablabla</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to put the `#a` div between `#d` and `#e`?

Check it live here:

http://sunnyweb.hu/test.php

Can I bring the "blablabla" before to the blue div without changing the div structure?

Comment: Don't know if I got what you want. Try giving `z-index : 3` to `div#con div#e`

Comment: Sherlock solved the mystery `div#e { z-index:3; }`

Comment: Hack: http://jsfiddle.net/pfAbS/ :)

Comment: In your source code (the .php) seams to be in the z.index order you are looking for. The only rule I dont like is the one that declares z.index=4 for all children of #con. But it does not matter because it wont compute for non positioned and the other divs will override the value. The painting order of the children divs will be will be from deep to surface ( b , c , d , a , e.) So if "before" means nearest to the observer, its all ready there. unless I  misunderstood something...

Comment: Do you want the blue div to align to the left in line with other divs or do you want something else, can you draw in paint or word etc an example of what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the first part of your question because I don't you if you want to position the divs with `position` so they are in some kind of order or `z-index` so they are stacked a certain way.

But the second part is real easy. All you need to do is set the `z-index` of `div#e` to something higher then `div#a`'s `z-index`.